# Запрос в SQL: группировка строк таблицы

Tags: mysql

Можно ли сгруппировать *строки* таблицы, если значение одного из полей одинаковое. Вот запрос

```
select UP.FIO,UP.DOLQ from COM_ANKETA A left join COM_ORG_ANKETA_UP UP on UP.VNESHID=A.ID where A.ID in (:V$mainID)
```

Этот запрос возвращает 4 строки с разным FIO, но у людей одинаков VNESHID, а мне нужно, чтобы эти люди группировались в *одну строку*.

Comment: Приведите пример заполнения таблицы. Ибо малопонятно что-то.

Comment: есть табл с полями ID и FIO у нескольких человек одинаковый ID и мне нужно чтобы запрос соеденял строки таблици с одинаковым ID в одно ну короче чтобы люди с одинаковыми IDшниками группировались

Answer (score 1):

Если верно понял - то так:

```
select
  GROUP_CONCAT( UP.FIO ) as FIO,
  UP.DOLQ
from
    COM_ANKETA A
  left join
    COM_ORG_ANKETA_UP UP
  on UP.VNESHID = A.ID
where
  A.ID in (:V$mainID)
group by
  UP.DOLQ
```

P.S: ИМХО:

1. Не пишите имена таблиц/полей - большими буквами...
2. Имена таблиц/полей - не несут смысла без знания контекста ( как минимум для меня - это набор плохо "транслит'ированых" букв )

Comment: Либо так, да, просто никогда не занимался скрещиванием "жирафа со слоном", обычно формирование отчетов идет построчно с указанием всех сотрудников :) 

@timka_s +1

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно результат запроса склеить в одну строку, то скорее всего придется использовать хранимые процедуры (функции). Вот только не знаю, как с ними в mysql.

Comment: дак да нужно сгруппировать грубо говоря по ID  только как это сделать понять не могу

Answer (score 0):

> вот примерно так мне надо а мне надо

Это стоящие знания для того чтобы правильно задать вопрос! **Мне так и надо, а надо мне так**. Велик и могуч русский язык.

```
SELECT ID,FIO FROM table WHERE ID='999';
```

Этим ты получишь всех с ID 999? ну а если нужно чтобы просто одна строка была то только в цикле после запроса, но есть ли в этом смысл?

Возьми и выведи всех в цикле и делай с ними что угодно.

на будущее, правильно поставленный вопрос - это 90% что ответ будет так же правилен и быстро написан.

**//upd**
    Этот запрос возвращает 4 строки с разным FIO, но у людей одинаков VNESHID, а мне нужно, чтобы эти люди группировались в одну строку.

Дык смотри ты получаешь правильные данные просто ты их потом правильно  в цикле обработай

```
$q="select UP.FIO,UP.DOLQ from COM_ANKETA A left join COM_ORG_ANKETA_UP UP on UP.VNESHID=A.ID where A.ID in (:V$mainID)";
$res=mysql_query($q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {
  echo $row['UP.FIO']."<br />";
 }
```

Ну и тут делай что хочешь, хочешь в одну строку, хочешь в две, три, пять, десять.

Comment: А как в цикле после запроса это сделать. Смысл в этом есть и еще как "выдернуть" всех с одинаковый ID. Я знаю нужен запрос именно на группировку по одинаковому ИД, а запрос у меня такой

    select
    UP.FIO,
    UP.DOLQ,
    UP.ADRES
    from COM_ANKETA A

    left join COM_ORG_ANKETA_UP UP on UP.VNESHID=A.ID
    where A.ID in (:V$mainID) и в табл COM_ORG_ANKETA_UP 

Нужно группировать по VNESHID учредителей, чтобы выводились все в одном поле, а сейчас выводятся в разных и в результате очень большой отчет получается, т.к. там много данных помимо этого выдергиваю.

Comment: Обнови правильно свой вопрос, со всеми полями со всеми таблицами, со всеми условиями, грамотно оформи, а твой комментария даже не дочитал, тяжело читать то что не читабельно.

Comment: обновил может так будет понятней чего я хочу ребята помогите плиз я реально голову сломал

Comment: кароче ерунда какаято получается никто понять меня не может, что я хочу ладно всем спасибо за помощ буду дальше гуглить может найду чего

Comment: тебе 2 ответа написали.

Если уж ты не можешь выразить что хочешь, то как мы "экстрасенсы" должны тебя понять.

Comment: ну собственно говоря я нашел что мне надо вот ссылка если кто захочет посмотреть  http://www.sql.ru/faq/faq_topic.aspx?fid=130
и отдельное спасибо всем кто пытался помочь